# How to set desired browser when triggering tests from CLI

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testng

I have a maven-testng-selenium framework where my default browser to run the tests is Chrome, but is configured to support Firefox and IE as well.

Browser type is selected from code, but I need a workaround to change it when I trigger the tests from
maven command or testng.xml file.

Does anyone know how I can change the browser by passing it's name as a variable in CLI?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the parameter using *system property* so that you will be able to parameterize your browser as from command line like `-Dproperty.name` as from sure-fire settings. Like:

```xml
<plugins>
    [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <propertyName>firefox</propertyName>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    [...]
</plugins>
```

You can also find more examples [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html).

In your test code you will read property value and set up your runtime to use the appropriate browser.